# JSON, объекты и массивы

Tags: json, php, массивы, объекты

Всем привет. Возникла у меня такая проблема с извлечением данных с помощью json.
Делаю так:

```
$info_json = $_GET['info'];
var_dump($info = json_decode($info_json));
```

В ответ получаю:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["resp"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["id"]=> int(266) ["name"]=> string(12) "Шамиль" ["last_name"]=> string(26) "Кадимагомедов" } } }
```

Хочу получить id, делаю так:

```
echo $info->{"id"};
```

В ответ пустота.

Делаю так:

```
var_dump($info->{"resp"});
```

Получаю ответ:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["id"]=> int(26633769) ["name"]=> string(12) "Шамиль" ["last_name"]=> string(26) "Кадимагомедов" } }
```

Так вот вопрос в чём, как мне получить данные пользователя? (`id`, `name`, `last_name`)

Answer (score 3):

`$info` — это объект с единственным свойством "resp" (`$info->resp`).

Далее, это свойство имеет значение массива, с единственным элементом с индексом `0`, вот так его получим (`$info->resp[0]`).

А этот нулевой элемент массива являет собой опять объект, с нужными вам свойствами `id`, `name` и `last_name`. Так, например, `id` можно получить вот так:

```
$id = $info->resp[0]->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
json_decode($_GET['info'], true);
```

Вместо объекта получите простой массив